# Segfault in pandas (python) due to missing numpy_helper.h file

Tags: python, pandas, segmentation-fault

I have a pandas DataFrame which I continuously expand with new rows and columns. In short, I'm counting words per minute from a Twitter stream; Unique words are added as columns; Every minute, I'm adding a new row.

After a while I get a segfault:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff1cd4dc3 in is_integer_object (obj=0x2b5cb10) at pandas/src/numpy_helper.h:48
48  pandas/src/numpy_helper.h: No such file or directory.
```

I installed pandas via pip, checked the installation, and indeed did not find the **numpy_helper.h** file nor the **scr** folder in **/home/ben/Envs/trending/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas**

Should this file (and others in src) be there? Did that cause a segfault?

**Update** More info on platform specifics:

```
Ubuntu 12.4 (x86_64)
```

Pip freeze:

```
Bottleneck==0.8.0
Cython==0.20.1
argparse==1.2.1
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
freetype-py==1.0
ipython==1.2.1
matplotlib==1.3.1
nose==1.3.0
numexpr==2.3.1
numpy==1.8.0
pandas==0.13.1
patsy==0.2.1
pymongo==2.6.3
pyparsing==2.0.1
python-dateutil==2.2
pytz==2013.9
scipy==0.13.3
six==1.5.2
statsmodels==0.5.0
tornado==3.2
tweepy==2.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

I've installed these packages in a virtualenv, by calling:

```
pip install <packagename>
```

Comment: pls post how you installed pandas, platform, and numpy version. this is not part of the run-time, but is needed for installation from source

Comment: FYI, frames are NOT threadsafe so you are you doing anything out of the ordinay? maybe show some code

Comment: I'm faced with threading, because the package Tweepy has implemented threading. Should I acquire a (threading) lock before reading/writing to the data frame?

Comment: yep; you need to isolate setting/reading in a locked object; note that 'continuously expanding with new rows/cols' is in general a bad idea. you should simply create new frames with the new data, then ``concat` them together to create new one. You will be copying data in both cases.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! I'm still wondering why `pip install` did not include numpy_helper.h, though. Any idea what might have gone wrong?

Comment: I think that's prob just a suprious error message, its definitly included in the distrbution (and you can't build w/o it)